# dtype seemingly ignored in read_csv during long loop

Tags: python, pandas

I've been experiencing an error with read_csv when looping over a long list of files.  Here's how I can reproduce it.

Given the following pseudo-code:

```
import pandas as pd

ll = []
for f in ec_files:
    fdf = pd.read_csv(f, dtype=dtypes, header=None,
                      parse_dates=[0, 1], index_col=1, names=colnames,
                      na_values=["NAN"], true_values=["t"],
                      false_values=["f"], low_memory=False)
    ll.append(pd.DataFrame(fdf.mean()).transpose())
```

where `ec_files` is a long list of path names to input files, `colnames` is a list of column names, and `dtypes` is a dictionary with the dtype for each column.  The files read without any problems individually, but when the above loop is used, then the process stops at random files with the following trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "junk.py", line 15, in
>   
>       false_values=["f"], low_memory=False)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in
>   parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 400, in
>   _read
>       data = parser.read()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 938, in
>   read
>       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1505, in
>   read
>       data = self._reader.read(nrows)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 849, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:9907)   File
>   "pandas/parser.pyx", line 945, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows
>   (pandas/parser.c:11161)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1047, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/parser.c:12536) 
>   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1126, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas/parser.c:13783)
>   ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 06-06 04:02:24.2

Something seems to break during parsing.  Why would this happen when using the loop but not with the files where this trace occurs?

Although some may find it hard to believe, the file where the error occurs changes every time the script is run, and yet those same files are read without any problems individually.  Below shows a traceback from another failing run of the script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "junk.py", line 16, in
>   
>       false_values=["f"], low_memory=False)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in
>   parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 400, in
>   _read
>       data = parser.read()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 938, in
>   read
>       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1505, in
>   read
>       data = self._reader.read(nrows)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 849, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:9907)   File
>   "pandas/parser.pyx", line 945, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows
>   (pandas/parser.c:11161)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1047, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/parser.c:12536) 
>   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1126, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas/parser.c:13783)
>   ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.5635078898.16

And a few lines from the top of the file where the last traceback above occurred:

```
2016-06-24 14:00:00,2016-06-24 14:00:00,-63.202653,67.693223,0.10,317.200,248.200,0.250,-0.770,-0.010,99.50,0.45,93.39,,,,1.12458829806343,1.56350788627135,1265.86,398.16,332.80,0.05078614,0.0061028,0.9117393,0.1835912,-0.4333494,-0.8065823,-0.649,1.14,-0.029,0.98,332.29,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2016-06-24 14:00:00,2016-06-24 14:00:00.1,-63.202653,67.693223,0.10,317.200,248.200,0.250,-0.770,-0.010,99.50,0.45,93.39,,,,1.12458829806343,1.56350788627135,1265.86,398.16,332.80,0.05210823,0.005970591,0.9118717,1.419696,-0.05049266,-1.156707,-0.638,1.139,-0.02,0.93,332.26,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2016-06-24 14:00:00,2016-06-24 14:00:00.2,-63.202653,67.693223,0.10,317.200,248.200,0.250,-0.770,-0.010,99.50,0.45,93.39,,,,1.12458829806343,1.56350788627135,1265.86,398.16,332.80,0.05038951,0.005441753,0.9117393,-0.2251475,0.1442362,0.6797946,-0.625,1.165,-0.017,0.95,332.27,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2016-06-24 14:00:00,2016-06-24 14:00:00.3,-63.202653,67.693223,0.10,317.200,248.200,0.250,-0.770,-0.010,99.50,0.45,93.39,,,,1.12458829806343,1.56350788627135,1265.86,398.16,332.80,0.05224044,0.0061028,0.9113424,-1.813954,-0.4432509,-0.2021224,-0.629,1.161,-0.041,0.97,332.28,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2016-06-24 14:00:00,2016-06-24 14:00:00.4,-63.202653,67.693223,0.10,317.200,248.200,0.250,-0.770,-0.010,99.50,0.45,93.39,,,,1.12458829806343,1.56350788627135,1265.86,398.16,332.80,0.05157939,0.00623501,0.9118717,0.1374433,-0.2023152,-1.166616,-0.595,1.166,-0.009,0.98,332.29,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

My version of pandas:

```
In [20]: pd.__version__
Out[20]: 
'0.19.0+git14-ga40e185'
```

Again, this (and any of the files where these random errors occur) read fine on their own with the very same read_csv command.  I'm afraid this may require supplying all the set of files to communicate.

Thanks for any feedback,
Seb

Comment: The error is telling you that you have an invalid float for one of your columns. The value is actually a date. This will fail regardless if there is a loop or not.

Comment: As I mentioned, the same file where this error happens is read fine individually. In fact all files in the list read fine individually with the very same read_csv command.

Comment: Forgive us @sluque. That is hard to believe. Please add `print(f)` inside of the loop. When it errs out, open the last printed file in console and post a few rows of its content for us so we can reproduce. It can also be you have different versions of file, depending on relative/absolute paths.

Comment: I am 100% sure there's only one version of each file in the collection, and I've edited the post to show a couple examples of the traceback, showing the failure in different files.  I've read these files individually without problems, so I'm certain the read_csv works for all the files.  Regardless, the fact that the error is thrown on different files tells me the problem is somewhere else.